# Is it correct to assume that savedInstanceState is NEVER null when activity is re-created?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my android app, I need to know whether an activity is created for the first time (`Context.startActivity()`), or re-created after being stopped (navigating back to the activity after is has been destroyed).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Having a look at the documentation, it seems to me that the `savedInstanceState` given to `Activity.onCreate()` will

- always be null if the activity is created for the first time
- never be null if the activity is re-created after having been destroyed

Is that correct, even if I don't implement `onSaveInstanceState()`? How can I test this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

By implementing `onSaveInstanceState` you are overriding it. Which means it will still get called when you don't override it. To test it you can rotate your app from portrait to landscape and vice-versa. It will destroy the `Activity` and re-create it. You will have a `Bundle` in `onCreate` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we change orientation of screen, activity life cycle sequence is onSaveInstaceState()-> onPause()->onStop()-> onCreate()->onStart()->onRestoreInstanceState()->onResume() So, Default values return by onSaveInstanceState() always null, which can pass as parameter to onCreate() method.